# Localization, escape html elements mid-sentence

Tags: translation, localization

I am trying to translate a few strings inside of a new plugin I'm about to release. I have a string set up like : 

`<?php _e('The image <em>MUST</em> be less than <strong>500 KB</strong> in size.', CUSTOM_TEXT_DOMAIN); ?>`

How would I go about escaping the  elements so they are not included in the poedit translation?

Thanks!

Comment: am I correct to assume I should use: `esc_html__(` and `esc_html_e(`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `printf` to put the markup into place after the translation. You can force the order with the right modifiers, but translators are probably smart enough to not really need that.

```
printf( __('The image %sMUST%s be less than %s500 KB%s in size.', CUSTOM_TEXT_DOMAIN), '<em>', '</em>', '<strong>', '</strong>' ) ;
```

I consider [Otto's post](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong) to be one of the definitive sources on how to translate strings in WordPress and one of his "rules" is don't translate HTML.